# SQLite Changing primary key value

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, primary-key

Is there any way to change the value of the only unique identifier for a row in SQLite? Something like

```
if(ID == 5) ID = 4;
```

I tried

```
UPDATE Table SET ID = Value WHERE ID = DifferentValue
```

But it does not seem to do a trick. 
The reason for this is that I don't auto-increment IDs as I prefer them to be set by programme because I have different methods when ID is odd and ID is even and I might need to switch the IDs in case some entry gets deleted so to compress the numbers so they don't leave blank ID spaces between them.

Programme is written in C# if that helps.

EDIT: The column is NOT truly dedicated as a PK in the db, it is jut NOT NULL integer that I control myself on non-duplicates so that it can serve as a PK

Comment: sounds like you will need to do 1 of 2 things.. `1` make a backup of the table change the Keys on that table to not be primary, then reseed the DB then Insert the records back in after you have updated the key to the proper value or get a hold of a very good DBA

Comment: Just one of many reasons why you should never try to stuff information into a column like that. If rows have to be flagged as one of two types (in your case you've hacked this together with your odd/even "trick" then you should add another column for that flag.

Comment: What do you mean "does not seem to do a trick"?  Do you get an error?  Are you sure value is not already present?   Odd, even, compress blanks - not good practices.

Comment: Ok, Seems that it really is a bad practice. I'll probably modify the logic of programme instead of trying to force it around with PK swapping